# Getting YouTube embed videos to target an iframe on another url on my site

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, youtube

My Homepage has links on to youtube videos that open in an iframe on the Homepage when I click on the video thumbnail/link.

Page1 - Has an iframe named 'Main'.

### I want the videos on the homepage, to target 'Main' on Page1 when I click on the thumbnail on the homepage.

So basically I want videos (which are listed on the homepage) to play in an iframe that exists on a different page.

Thanks for any help,
Chris

Comment: So don't make your links target the iframe then - but let them change the document loaded in the "main" window instance instead, to your specific /gameX/ page. Each of those pages would then have to load the corresponding game in its own iframe to begin with, statically.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I follow you, please could you give an example of what you mean? Many thanks

Comment: I edited my post to make it more simple to understand what I want. Sorry about the large bold text, I can't seem to get rid of that formatting.

Comment: so its like www.homepage.com and www.homepage.com/page1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you want the user to click a YouTube thumbnail on your homepage and then navigate to another page where there is an iframe inside which the YouTube video should be loaded, correct?

**home.html**

```
<a href="page1.html?yt=eokuVGX7oAI">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/eokuVGX7oAI/3.jpg" alt="" />
</a>

<a href="page1.html?yt=pI0EpHD43Xo">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/pI0EpHD43Xo/3.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

**page1.html**

```
<iframe name="Main" id="Main" src="about:blank" width="640" height="320"></iframe>

<script>
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const ytId = urlParams.get('yt');
    const ytLink = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + ytId + '?autoplay=1';
    document.getElementById('Main').src = ytLink;
</script>
```

Note: Even though it worked like a charm during my testing, autoplay might not work on all browsers / devices because of restrictions. There's no way around that limitation.

**page1.html (with default)**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="main" id="main" ></iframe>   

<script>
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const ytId = urlParams.get('yt');
    if(ytId==null) {
        //Parameter empty, default to whatever video
        document.getElementById('main').src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/PS9EBbgf0dk?autoplay=1';
    } else {
        const ytLink = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + ytId + '?autoplay=1';
        document.getElementById('main').src = ytLink;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you volkerschulz! It works great! However, the iframe on Page1, already has a video loaded into it by default. The code you supplied makes that iframe blank if i just go to Page1 (not through the youtube thumbs.
It is putting id='main' into the existing iframe that stops the default vid from being there. Here is my iframe code I am using -

Comment: `  $str.=' <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$video->YouTubeID.'?controls=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="main" id="main" ></iframe>'; `

Comment: I strongly suggest to not use the src of the iframe for a default video to be loaded, but rather do this in JS (see additional example **page1.html (with default)**). This way the browser doesn't unnecessarily starts to load the default video before is it being replaced by the dynamically selected video.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Works perfectly now, and I'll take your advice and not use the src of iframe. I really appreciate your help and efficiency. Many thanks again.
 PS- it won't let me award bounty for another 2 hours, so I'll nip back later and do that.

Comment: Glad that I could be of help. If you don't mind, please also mark the answer as the accepted answer (if at all possible). Thank you!